# ASP.NET MVC jQuery HTML5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have three .cshtml files: 
_ProductSelection.cstml -> this defines the html table

```
@model List<..Rate>
<table id="productgrid">
 <thead>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
     @Html.Partial("_ProductRows", Model)
</tbody>
</table>
```

_ProductRows.cshtml-> this has some attributes added to each tr and td

```
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var rate in Model)
        {
            <tr class="@(rate.IsSelected ? "selected" : "")" data-base="@rate.BaseCharge" data-planname="@rate.PlanName" >
...
```

ProductSelection.cshtml->actual view call from MVC controller:

```
    ....
     @Html.Partial("_ProductSelection", Model.Rates)
    ...
    @section scripts {
       ..
        var table = $('#productgrid'),
          tbody = table.find('tbody'),
       ...

     $(function () {
....
     tbody.find('tr').each(function (index, elem) {
                    var self = $(elem),
                        base = parseFloat(self.attr('data-base')),
         .....
```

This is working code I can access all the *data* attribute in productSelection.cshtml, which are set in tr tag of _ProductRows.cshtml file. e.g.  data-base, data-planname

The problem is: I added some more data attribute to _ProductRows tr tag, but new data attributes are not visible in ProductSelection.cshtml, when i debug in google chrome and check value of *elem* it only has data attributes define before, newly added attribute in not in 'attribute' list of elem. In bellow example i don't see newly added data-credit.

```
<tr class="@(rate.IsSelected ? "selected" : "")" data-base="@rate.BaseCharge" data-planname="@rate.PlanName" data-credit="@rate.Credit" >
```

I added almost 20 more data attribute, none of them are visible while debugging in chrome. in Rate model I added all these new fields and populated it from values from database.

Comment: The data attributes are added in the back-end right? If so, does the newly added attribute appear in the markup when you inspect it?

Comment: yes added new fields to database. and populated Rate model. what's meaning of appear in markup? I am new to web development, can you please explain.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Caching in Chrome? You might be looking at a cached version.

Comment: yes i did. I also tried incongnito mode.

Comment: Did you check if there is value in `rate.Credit` and other new fields you added?

Comment: @ksam as in when you inspect the page, is the new data attribute in the html? To inspect, right click on the element and select inspect

Comment: @adiga: yes it has values.

Comment: @Huangism: i don't display those fields on page, it is use for calculation...so can't inspect it.. However, on one the attribute when i "Evaluate in Console" it shows me following: (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of app.binding did not set the binding field
ProductSelection:1 (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of webstore.binding did not set the binding field
ProductSelection:1 (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of runtime.binding did not set the binding field
3ProductSelection:1 Previous API instantiation failed.
self.attr('data-energycharge1')
undefined

Comment: var self = $(elem)

Comment: @ksam You can still find those fields as long as they are part of the html. Or display them for testing. If you can find those field in the html then you can easily see if your data attribute are there or not. I don't understand the backend stuff, I am giving you a way to debug

Comment: that's the point, i don't see those fields at all. and as i said they are the *data* attribute of tr tag.

Comment: We understand they are not displaying. The question is, if you right click on the `tr` and select "Inspect", are you able to see the markup with the values? (even if it's not rendered)

Comment: no values in markup.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone for response.

I found out the reason why new attributes are not appearing in "elem".

on ProductSelection.cshtml there is one more function which added attributes to tr tag, which overwrites the attributes added in _ProductRows.cshtml.